# Gram matrix of QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ be a full-column rank matrix and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector. At the moment I am performing the following computations:

- $Q, R = \texttt{QR}(A)$
- $y = x - 2QQ^\top x$

Is there a way to obtain $y$ without computing the QR decomposition?

## Notes

The `QR()` function that I am using is the `scipy.linalg.qr` with `mode='economic'`, meaning that $Q$ is a $n\times m$ matrix.

I think it should be possible to do this without computing the QR decomposition because the operation $QQ^\top x$ essentially is a projection of $x$ onto the column space of $Q$. But that same column space is spanned by the columns in $A$..

Comment: $Q$ is orthogonal, so $QQ^\top = 1$ and $y = -x$.

Comment: My bad, I am using the economic version of $Q$, which has the same shape as $A$ (as you would expect as we want the resulting column vectors to span the same space as the columns of $A$ do)

Comment: which one between $n$ and $m$ is greater?

Comment: @Exodd The input space is larger than the output space $n> m$

Answer (score 2):

The projection $\hat x$ of $x$ onto the image of $A$ is
$$
     \hat x = A(A^T A)^{-1} A^T x. \tag{1}
$$
so $y = x - 2 A(A^T A)^{-1} A^T x $.

This is a well known formula in the topic "linear least square problem".
If you want to fully understand where it comes from, you can have look on this topic on Wikipedia or, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831234/derive-least-square-equation-ata-hatx-atb-from-a-hatx-b-22?rq=1).

I'll try to give a quick answer:

In the linear least square problem, we want to find the best approximated solution to the overdetermined system $Au = x$, i.e. find $\hat u$ that minimizes the norm $\|Au - x\|_2$. One can show (see the link) that you can get $\hat u$ by solving the so called normal equation:
$$ 
 A^T A u = A^T x. \tag{2}
$$
Since $A$ has full column-rank, $A^T A$ is invertible so we obtain $\hat u = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T x$. Now, note that $A \hat u$ is the vector in $\mathrm{im}\, A$ that lies closest to $x$ (recall that $\hat u$ minimizes $\|A u - x\|_2$), so $\hat x = A \hat u$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $\mathrm{im}\, A$.

In theory, you can use the formulas $(1)$ or $(2)$, but from a computational point of view, this isn't very effective (calculating an inverse matrix is a no-go). That's why the QR-decomposition is often used. Other matrix decompositions, like the singular value decomposition or Cholesky decomposition (for Hermitian positive matrices), can also be used.

Suggested exercise: if you substitute $A=QR$ into the formula $(1)$, you should retrieve $\hat x = QQ^T x$.

Comment: Thank you! So perhaps I should stick to the more accurate $QR$ decomposition, even though it might be more expensive?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you need. If you are only working with small matrices and want to do your calculations by hand, I think it's ok to use the normal equations. If not, just go for the QR-decomposition. Also... $\hat x = QQ^T x$ is a nicer and shorter expression than equation (1).

Comment: Makes sense! Apart from solving the linear system in your equation $(1)$, is there another method that is perhaps as accurate/stable as the QR decomposition but cheaper?

Comment: I guess I am also not sure how expensive the QR decomposition would be in terms of $n$ and $m$..

Comment: I think QR decomposition is the best choice to go for. Unfortunately, I cannot support this claim. I don't remember the complexities of and condition numbers in every decomposition. I want to look it up, but I currently have no access to the book "Numerical Linear Algebra" of Trefethen and Bau.